# An alphametic puzzle about Thomas Edison

Tags: alphametic

Thomas Alva Edison was born on February 11, 1847.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Edison

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [image]
>
>  It is given to us that **R = 2**.
>
>  Now, INV - ab is a single-digit number and ab is a multiple of 11. Even if ab were as high as 88 and INV as low as 100, their difference would be 12 which has two digits. Therefore ab = 99 and 100 <= INV <= 108 (not 109 since 109 - 99 = 10, again two digits). But that implies **E = 9**, and IN will always be 10 (hence **I = 1** and **N = 0**).
>
>  [image: image2]

> Also, I = 1 implies cd = 11. e0 - 11 is a single digit so e = 2. But that makes f = 7, meaning ?f = 77 since it has to be a multiple of 11, meaning **D = 7**. Also, g9 - 77 = 2 so g = 7. That results in 10V - 99 = 7, meaning 10V = 106 (so **V = 6**).
>
>  [image]

> 9T - hi is a single digit again. So hi would never be able to be as high as 77, since even if we make 9T as low as 90, 90 - 77 = 13. Also hi cannot be 99 since it is implied that the difference is nonzero, so hi = 88 which implies **S = 8**. Therefore T = 3, 4, or 5. Also jO is a multiple of 11 since jO - ?? is zero, so j = O.
>
>  If we make T = 4, then 9T - 88 = 94 - 88 = 6 = j = O, but O cannot be 6 since V already is. If we make T = 5, then j = O = 7, but O cannot be 7 since D already is. Therefore **T = 3**, and so j = **O = 5**. We can then complete the alphametic.
>
>  [image]

In conclusion:

> N = 0, I = 1, R = 2, T = 3, O = 5, V = 6, D = 7, S = 8, and E = 9.